# RGB to HEX JavaScript function working in Chrome, but not Firefox or Safari

Tags: javascript

I recently found (on SO.com for that matter) a nifty little function that converts a RGB value to its hex correspondent. As an argument, I pass the values of the CSS "color" attributes (e.g.: "rgb(45,187,251)"). Here's the function:

```
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    function hex(x) {
        return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }
    return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
}
```

It works perfectly in Chrome, but the Firebug console in Firefox gives the following error:

> rgb is null
>
> return "#" + hex(rgb[1](http://goalcandy.com)) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);

Why does this happen?

You can see it in use on [goalcandy.com](http://goalcandy.com). Just hit "Start now", then click on "Save" on the left side of the screen and watch the Firebug console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracing though on that page using Firebug, in the call

```
data += rgb2hex(jqMesh.css('border-color')) + '|'
```

at line 1516 -- the call to `jqMesh.css('border-color')` is returning an empty string.

Calling `jqMesh.css('color')` in the Firebug console while stopped at that breakpoint returns "rgb(68, 68, 68)"

Comment: That's true. But why is the call jqMesh.css('border-color') returning an empty result?

Comment: I've added an alert call right before the line "data+= rgb2h...", and Firefox doesn't show the first 3 values, which are for "border-color", "border-width" and "border", but it shows it for "background-color". Chrome on the other hand shows all 3. This is one of the weirdest errors I've ever encountered...

Comment: @AndreiOniga - Even weirder, you say it works in Chrome but not Safari, and they are both WebKit based browsers. [MDN says](http://developer.mozilla.org/docs/CSS/border-color) "The border-color CSS property is a shorthand for setting the color of the four sides of an element's border" so maybe Firefox explodes it into its non-shorthand form when it processes the CSS rule.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out not to be a problem with the *rgb2hex()* function, but rather with the jquery's *css()* method in Firefox. Namely, in Firefox, calling *.css("border-color")* returns a void value, as opposed to *.css("border-top-color")* for instance. Chrome understands the first version too.